# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

**Обновление**

```
Firefox == 58.0.2   
selenium == 3.9.0  
geckodriver == 0.19.1  
Python == 3.6.4
Linux (64bit) на базе Debian
```

`chmod +x`-нутый *geckodriver* расположен в `usr/local/bin`. Запускается через терминал (Уже. Спасибо замечанию от jfs).

Firefox расположен в `/usr/bin/firefox`

В файле *.bashrc* я прописала в конец строчку для Firefox:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/firefox
```

Теперь когда я запускаю нижний код:

```
from selenium import webdriver

web = webdriver.Firefox()
link = web.get('https://duckduckgo.com')
need = link.find_element_by_class_name('logo_homepage__tt').text
print(need)
```

Выдаётся ошибка:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Comment: Гляньте [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870530/how-to-install-geckodriver-in-ubuntu) первый ответ, попробуйте повторить все пункты с начала.

Comment: скорее всего драйвр не имеет прав на запуск

Comment: надо сделать его исполняемым `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver`

Comment: К сожалению ничего не помогло. :( Может из-за версии Firefox ?

Comment: @jfs, откатилась до selenium 2.53.6 версии, и сделала как вы написали. Команда `geckodriver --version` выдаёт:   
geckodriver v0.9.0  
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver  

This program is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0.  
You can obtain a copy of the license at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой баг (или фича?) на последних версиях FF. Проявляется, вроде как, когда стоит другой браузер по умолчанию. Лечить можно явным указанием бинарника браузера:

```
web = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver', 
    firefox_binary='/path/to/firefox/binary'
)
```

P.S. откатываться на такие "древние" селениум и гекодрайвер - сомнительный фикс вашей проблемы. Лучше наоборот поставьте все самое новое (если нет непреодолимых препятствий для этого), включая сам браузер FF, и попробуйте мой совет.

Comment: Я решила проблему, но спасибо.