# Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: python

Пытаюсь открыть браузер при помощи selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = './geckodriver',firefox_binary='/usr/bin/firefox',firefox_profile='./prof/')
```

при запуске выдает ошибку

```
Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786593/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabiliti

Comment: Да, я видел этот вопрос. Указал бинарное расположение к браузеру и к файлу geckodriver но проблему не решило, если не прописывать пути пишет geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: В таком случае добавьте в переменную `PATH` местоположение исполняемого `geckodriver` и перезагрузите систему

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю зачем добавлять путь в PATH, я попробовал скопировать файл geckodriver в /usr/local/bin. Из командной строки вызываю geckodriver все океу. Запускаю код browser = webdriver.Firefox()  - ошибка из прошлого комментария

Comment: Это нужно, потому что `PATH` является базовым источником для него. Если не хотите добавлять путь туда, тогда воспользуйтесь `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\Selenium\...')` и укажите явно путь к исполняемому файлу.
Или же поместите его в Python/Scripts/... и укажите `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: Добавил путь в переменную PATH, ошибка не пропала, указал путь через executable_path =, вернулась ошибка как из заголовка вопроса Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: После добавления в `PATH` произвели перезагрузку? Если ничего вышеперечисленное не помогло, то я могу посоветовать лишь тщательную проверку совместимостей Selenium + Geckodriver + Firefox

Comment: а где можно посмотреть совместимости?

Comment: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html

Answer (score -1):

Вообщем не совсем понял в чем проблема но вопрос решился. При запуске кода из среды разработки постоянно вылетала ошибка `geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` 
При запуске скрипта через терминал, `geckodriver` ноходится и все запускается.

Comment: Является ли гильотина решением вопроса перхоти? Автор пишет, что ему помогло, но народ настаивает, что это не способ решения. Кто прав? Ой... я имел в виду, что отказ от виртуальной среды не является решением и, скорее всего, не стоит публиковать это как ответ.

Comment: Других решений пока не видно